# Convert Gradle configuration into Ant path

Tags: gradle, ant

How do I convert a Gradle configuration into an Ant path?

`build.gradle` snippet

```
configurations {
    install
}
dependencies {
    install "com.oracle:ojdbc6:12.1.0.2"
    install project(':myproject')
    install ...
}
```

The `install` configuration (including its transitive dependencies) is needed as a parameter of an ant task:

```
ant.updateDatabase(classpathref: 'installCpRef')
```

Using `ant.path(id: 'installCpRef', location: configurations.install.asPath)` does not work, since `ant.path` treats the location as a single pathspec. This only works as long as there is just one element on the path.

One solution is to specify all dependencies manually, like that

```
ant.path(id: 'install.cp') {
    fileset(dir: '<aPath>', includes: '<aJar>')
    fileset(dir: '<anotherPath>') {
            include (name: '**/*.jar')
    }
}
```

This implies re-declaring all dependencies, including the transitive dependencies, which is not acceptable.

How do I automatically convert the `configuration.install` into an ant path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [path-like structures](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) in ant docs

> The location attribute specifies a single file or directory relative
>   to the project's base directory (or an absolute filename), while the
>   path attribute accepts colon- or semicolon-separated lists of
>   locations.

This should work:

```
ant.classpath(id: 'install.cp', path: configurations.install.asPath)
ant.updateDatabase(classpathref: 'install.cp')
```

Comment: great, I've totally missed the `path` part in the docs. `ant.path(id: 'install.cp', path: configurations.install.asPath)` works but `ant.classpath(id: 'install.cp', path: configurations.install.asPath)`does not.